# PHP Trying to get variables from form

Tags: php, html, variables, post, request

For some reason, when I submit my form and it goes off to the PHP. The PHP isn't getting the variables from the HTML.

My index.php forms code:

```
<form method="post" action="postConsole.php"> 
Target:
<select name="target" size ="1">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">All</option>
  <option value="1001">LocalHost</option>
</select>
Event:
<select name="dropevent" size ="1">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose</option>
  <option value="PlayerMoveEvent">PlayerMoveEvent</option>
  <option value="PlayerJoinEvent">PlayerJoinEvent</option>
  <option value="PlayerQuitEvent">PlayerQuitEvent</option>
  <option value="PlayerRespawnEvent">PlayerRespawnEvent</option>
  <option value="PlayerInteractEvent">PlayerInteractEvent</option>
  <option value="PlayerKickEvent">PlayerKickEvent</option>
</select>
Command: <input type="text" size="24" maxlength="24" name="command"><br /> 
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Then this is my postConsole.php file:

```
<?php
  $command = $_REQUEST['command'];
  $event = $_POST["dropevent"];
  $target = $_POST["target"];
  $PME = "PlayerMoveEvent";
  $PJE = "PlayerJoinEvent";
  $PQE = "PlayerQuitEvent";
  $PRE = "PlayerRespawnEvent";
  $PIE = "PlayerInteractEvent";
  $PKE = "PlayerKickEvent";
  echo $command . "/" . $event . "/" . $target;
```

When I put in the details and press submit, it shows "**//**". Does anbody know why this is happening? I would really appreciate the help.

PS: I know $command,$event,$target, are all different. That's because I kept trying different ways to get the variables, so please don't comment on that part.

Comment: `var_dump()` it so see what is being sent

Comment: Tested your code - works fine for me.

Comment: Looks fine to me too, the error isn't in the code that you share, must be hidden somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This part of code, that you show us is correct. If your display is "//" probably in your postConsole.php file just before the code that you show us you might do something like this:

```
unset($_POST);
//or
$_POST = array();

unset($_REQUEST);
//or
//$_REQUEST = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

try using:-

```
print_r($_POST);
```

to check whether form is submitting all the values or not

Answer (score 0):

Try check variables

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
var_dump($_POST);
```

If there are empty after POST request, check if POST is enabled in PHP directives, use phpinfo() or by ini_get() and if not enabled - change php.ini

```
// must contain "P" as POST, for example "GPCS"
echo ini_get('variables_order');

// must contain "P" as POST, for example "GP"
echo ini_get('request_order');

// must be enable, for example 1 or "On"
echo ini_get('enable_post_data_reading');
```